# xml parsing and convert values to string C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML format like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<abresponse IssuerId="5" ReturnCode="Success" Version="12.2">
    <XMLAuthenticateResponse>
        <ACL>
            <ACL Name="PM.ADMIN" Value="1" /> 
            <ACL Name="PM.APPROVE" Value="1" /> 
            <ACL Name="PM.LOGIN" Value="1" /> 
            <ACL Name="PM.SUPPORT" Value="1" /> 
        </ACL>
        <User EMailAddress="abc@xyz.com" GroupName="Program Administrator" UserId="2095965" Username="test" /> 
    </XMLAuthenticateResponse>
</abresponse >
```

How can i take the ReturnCode from the XML..

I am getting this as a API Response, so i have converted that

```
XElement response = XElement.Parse(xDoc.OuterXml)
string retcode=response.Descendants("OrbiscomResponse")
                       .Attributes("ReturnCode")
                       .FirstOrDefault()
                       .Value
                       .Tostring();
```

Comment: Post your current code and explain the problem you're having so we can help fix it.

Comment: Show us your efforts

Comment: You can load xml as `string`, find `ReturnCode=` and obtain the value. Theoretically.

Comment: Try `XmlElement.GetAttribute Method`

Comment: Your XML has `abresponse ` but your code is looking for `OrbiscomResponse`  Also what is `xDoc`?  You shouldn't need to parse the xml twice.

Comment: If the answer by Volkan Paksoy worked, perhaps you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the Descendants call and it should work fine:

```
string retcode = response
           .Attributes("ReturnCode")
           .FirstOrDefault()
           .Value
           .ToString();
```